# How to simplify this expression that contains exponential terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

In a multiple choice exam , I encountered the following question. The answer to the question is $$ \frac{17}{8}.$$

The question is:

$$\frac{16^{x+1}+4^{2x}}{2^{x-3}8^{x+2}} \text{ is ? }$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Write the terms in the fraction in a common base: $2$

$4 = 2^2,\; 8 = 2^3,\;16 = 2^4$.

$$\frac{(2^4)^{x+1}+(2^2)^{2x}}{2^{x-3}(2^3)^{x+2}}$$

Then use the fact that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, and follow by factoring. You'll also want to remember that $a^na^m = a^{n + m}$.

Comment: Im sorry , but ive been at this for a half hour, ive reached this far , but i dont know what to do with the numerator.  What/how do i factorize.

Comment: $$\frac{(2^4)^{x+1}+(2^2)^{2x}}{2^{x-3}(2^3)^{x+2}} = \frac{2^{4x + 4} + 2^{4x}}{2^{x-3}2^{3x + 6}}= \frac{2^{4x}(2^4 + 1)}{2^{x-3+3x+6}} = \frac{2^{4x}(17)}{2^{4x + 3}} = \frac{2^{4x}(17)}{2^{4x}{2^3}}$$ Now cancel, then evaluate.

Comment: OK , i made a mistake and i've goten it  now, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!